# Sequelize v5 Poorly Formatted Join with Nested Include

Tags: sequelize.js, nested-includes

I am using Sequelize v6 with the mariadb dialect.

I have query that looks like this:

```
db.RunVersion.findAll({
  include: [{
      model: db.Run,
      include: [{
         as: "Watchers",
         model: db.RunWatchers,
         required: true,
         where: {id: user.id}
      }],
   }],
   where: where
}]
```

This produces a WHERE clause that looks like this:

```
FROM RunVersions AS RunVersion
LEFT OUTER JOIN (Runs AS Run
INNER JOIN RunWatchers AS Runs->Watchers ON Run.id = Run->Watchers.wid
AND Run->Watchers.un = 'mrprice') ON RrunVersion.rid = Run.id
```

This returns bad results. I expect the WHERE clause to look like this:

```
FROM RunVersions AS RunVersion
LEFT OUTER JOIN Runs AS Run ON RunVersion.rid = Run.id
INNER JOIN RunWatchers AS Run->Watchers ON Run.id = Run->Watchers.wid AND Run-Watchers.unname = 'mrprice'
```

Any ideas why this is happening?

Comment: did you try `subquery: false`?

Comment: Yes. Tried it on every part of the query and no luck.

Comment: Should be at the root level of options. Did the SQL query change after that even a bit?

Comment: db.RunVersion.findAll({
  include: [{
      model: db.Run,
      include: [{
         as: "Watchers",
         model: db.RunWatchers,
         required: true,
         where: {id: user.id}
      }],
   }],
   where: where,
   subquery: false
}]

Query looks the same.

Comment: Sorry, my bad. It should be `subQuery`

Comment: Still the same.

Comment: Can you indicate `required: false` for RunWatchers?

Comment: Yes, and that formats it correctly but brings back way more records.

Comment: Then just add a condition to `RunWatchers` like `{ id: { [Op.ne]: null } }`

Comment: Kind of a hack but that worked!  Thanks.

Comment: It's because usually if you use LEFT OUTER JOIN then you need to use it in all further joins as well, otherwise, you can end up with not a result you're expecting